# laravel excel with upserts not updating data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I have a csv file with data inside. I want import it to my database. If there's repeated data in csv file, I don't want it to create new repeated records, what I want is to update it.

**But the problem is, it's creating new repeated records.**

Controller (abbreviated):

```
Excel::import(new FruitImport, $request->file('fruits_file'), \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::XLSX);
```

Import File (abbreviated):

```
class FruitImport implements ToModel, WithUpserts, ... {
    public function model(array $row) {
        return new Fruit([
            'color' => $row[0],
            'taste' => $row[1],
            'smell' => $row[2],
            'name' => $row[3],
            'price' => $row[4],
            'supplier_id' => $row[5],
            ...
         ]);
    }

    public function uniqueBy() {
        return ['color', 'taste', 'smell', 'name'];
    }

    ...
}
```

So basically, if I import a csv file containing rows with same color, taste, smell, name to my database, I want it to be updated. Same thing if any record in my database has same color, taste, smell and name data.

My table:

```
Field    | Type        | Key  | ...
id       | big int un..| Pri  |
color    | varchar(12) |      |
taste    | varchar(12) |      |
smell    | varchar(12) |      |
name     | char(20)    |      |
...
```

I'm using Laravel 8, Php 8.0.2 and Mysql 8.
Laravel excel is version 3.1

My references:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts

https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/model.html#upserting-models

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure [Upserts in Laravel Excel](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/model.html#upserting-models) are what you want. Specifically, there is a condition listed in the documentation that is (in my opinion) overly restrictive.

> All databases except SQL Server require the uniqueBy columns to have a "primary" or "unique" index.

To import spreadsheet data in a custom way, you can always use the `ToCollection` concern. This will give you full control over how the entries are saved.
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/collection.html

Use the `updateOrCreate()` method to look for existing entries with the options you have specified by passing them in the first array, with the remaining data in the second array.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts

```php
class FruitImport implements ToCollection ... 
{    
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row) 
        {
            Fruit::updateOrCreate(
                [
                    'color' => $row[0],
                    'taste' => $row[1],
                    'smell' => $row[2],
                    'name' => $row[3]
                ],
                [
                    'price' => $row[4],
                    'supplier_id' => $row[5],
                    ...
                ]
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not exactly what I was looking for but, really helpful. Thank you

Comment: @Ricardinho hi, what was the solution for you because i have same pb